# How to build a form that is in grid format with a title, img, checkbox for each item in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a text file which is formatted with titles, location of images, and a bunch of other info. I wrote a python class which will parse this text file and build an object that holds a title, an image, and the info associated with it. It returns a list of these objects.

I want to display each object in this list in Django using an html table. If the user checks the save checkbox and then submits the form, all checked objects will be saved into the database. Basically, each table element will reflect a particular object and will look like this:

[image: format]

So in a simple case, I have something like this:

```
Class ImageContainerModel(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField()
      img = models.CharField()
      info = models.CharField()
```

I'm not sure how to write this. I've done something like this before, but it was very ugly. What I had done previously was, I got my object list and passed it into a form as a choices argument, then I modified the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget by changing the way it displays the html.

I can do this again, but is there a simpler way? I thought about just passing the object list to the template directly and then building a table from there using template tags, but I'm not sure how to insert the checkboxes for each and then validate it in my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a [Model formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)? The only issue here would be that it requires a properly formed queryset, which means you'd need to save your ImageContainer objects first and then delete them if the user doesn't click save.

Off the top of my head, something like this could probably work with some tweaking:

--- In forms.py ---

```
class ImageContainerSaveForm(forms.Form):
    confirm_save = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        confirm_save = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_save', False)

        if not confirm_save:
            self.instance.delete()
```

--- In your view ---

```
ImageContainerFormSet = modelformset_factory(ImageContainerModel, fields=(), form=ImageContainerSaveForm, extra=0)

containers = get_containers()

if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = ImageContainerFormSet(request.POST, queryset=containers)

    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return redirect('somewhere')

else:
    formset = ImageContainerFormSet(queryset=containers)
```